# Enable Write permission on hard disk

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, permissions, hard-drive

I have installed ubuntu on my SSD in dual boot, with windows 10. I have another hard disk to be used by both operating systems, partition type basic data and contains FAT(32bit). I cannot write using ubuntu but can write using Windows. How to enable write permission on that disk? I am new to linux migrated from windows. Thank you..........

Comment: Is the file-system you're trying to write to *clean*?  ie. windows hasn't left it *dirty* due to hibernate or fast-boot.  Look at when the file-system is mounted, if it was mounted RW (*read write*) but due to *dirty* state (*logs will show this, or command if mounted at terminal meaning you don't need to go look in logs*) it's mounted instead as RO (*read only*) to prevent dataloss due to *unclean* state (ie. *some metadata of the file-system is stored in hibernate or fastboot file used by windows & not accessible when windows isn't running*).

Comment: You should also provide your Ubuntu product/release details, so we can better understand your issue, along with any commands & error messages that explain your error.

Comment: Have you tried opening Terminal and entering `sudo -H nautilus` to open Nautilus as root? Or you can try installing `sudo apt install nautilus-admin` and open the SSD or it's folders as administrator.

Comment: Best not to use FAT32 for larger data partitions. It cannot store file over 4GB and has no journal to help repairs. Use NTFS. But Windows fast start up must be off & Windows updates may turn it back on. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation How you mount in /etc/fstab is the default permissions for Windows file systems as they do not support Linux permissions.

Comment: Also maximum partition size for FAT32 is 32 GB